# Lookup an array in Excel and return specific elements

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I'm having trouble writing a formula to look up an array and then return a specific element.

This table has dates mapped to deposits, and there might be 3 or more cash deposits in one day, but instead of consolidating the cash desposits, we want to leave them separate.

```
01/01/2014  526.62
01/01/2014  1015.07
01/02/2014  973.44
01/02/2014  675.05
01/03/2014  1220.82
01/03/2014  1422.1
01/05/2014  762.67
01/06/2014  622.38
01/06/2014  579.12
```

I want to look up all deposits a day, and then for the first element in that array, call it "Deposit #1", call the second one "Deposit #2", and so on for each deposit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
="Deposit #"&COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)
```

copied down to suit.